# iOS bluetooth development: mimicking the SPP profile

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to interface a custom device with bluetooth 2.1 (it has the RN-42 chip), with an iPhone and iPad. The device uses the Bluetooth SPP profile. From my research it appears that iOS supports Bluetooth Low Energy and accessories through the MFi ("Made for iPod") program.

The device I have is BT2.1, so doesn't have BLE. The MFi program requires hardware modification, which isn't an option. Is there other ways of interfacing the device, ideally not jailbraking them?

I've also found this [list](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204387) of supported profiles in iOS. Can one of these profiles be used to "wrap" the SPP profile? Or somehow circumvent it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to interface it by using an intermediate device (Arduino+shields?) that supports both BLE and classic Bluetooth SPP to relay data.